# Text case-insitive search with crate.io SQL

Tags: sql, crate

What is the proper SQL syntax to search an array text in the `crate database`?

My example table is:

```
create table 
tasks(user string, entry array(object as (taskid string, eTime timestamp))).
```

I tried the following which give a syntax error:

```
select * from program where any(entry['taskid']) ~* '.*cleanup.*';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [ANY operator](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/queries.html#any-array) would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE '.*cleanup.*' ~* ANY(entry['taskid']);
```

However, `PCRE` are currently not supported in combination with `ANY`. An alternative would be the [`LIKE`](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/queries.html#like) predicate, but that is not case-insensitive (and can be quite slow if it starts with a wildcard character);

So ultimately, you could ...

... either use a [fulltext index](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/ddl.html#sql-ddl-index-fulltext) on the `entry['taskid']` column with a [`lowercase` analyzer](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/analyzer.html#lowercase-tokenfilter) (which is probably not the best solution, because I assume `taskid` is a single word and you want to use it "as is" also),

... or split up the array values into separate rows so you have a schema like:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  user string,
  entry OBJECT AS (
    taskid STRING,
    etime TIMESTAMP
  )
) ...
```

The you can use

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE entry['taskid'] ~* '.*cleanup.*';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that REGEX operations can be very expensive. Using an Analyzer is usually the better option. If you need the column as-is in it's original form too you can use a [named index column definition](https://crate.io/docs/reference/sql/ddl.html#defining-a-named-index-column-definition)